# chronologically， interpretation comes before/predate written translation

Tags: tense

> Chronologically, interpretation comes before/predates written translation.

In this sentence,should I use present or past tense? What if the following passage is about the old definition and stories of translation?

Comment: If you mean the sentence in your title, you should quote it in the body of the question as well. Yes, _comes before_ and _predates_ should be in the present tense. The sense of 'in the past' is included in the meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're discussing things in terms of their chronological order, ***you have the choice*** to describe them either as events that occurred whenever they occurred in the past, or as events that are presently on a timeline.

> Chronologically, interpretation **comes** before written translation.
> Chronologically, interpretation **came** before written translation.
> Chronologically, interpretation **predates** written translation.
> Chronologically, interpretation **predated** written translation.

These are all correct. The only difference is the nuance of either focusing on the overall chronology of the events on the timeline (present simple), or focusing on the time that item first appeared (simple past). That's a style choice.